# get a CouchDB attachment and show it on a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, couchdb

I want to show in my html page an image that I've attached in a document on couchdb.
How I can do this using javascript (jquery)?

I solved using

```
$.couch.db("mydb").view(...)
```

to obtain the id of document that I'm interesting. And

```
$.couch.db("mydb").openDoc(id, {...})
```

to obtain the image coded in base64. After that I put this base64's code in tag

```
<img src="data:image/jpg; base64, ...">
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do this by adding `img` tag:

```
<img src="http://somehost/somedatabase/document/attachment">
```

Comment: Oh, @Morris, that was not obvious from your question :)